# Initial Route Name not working in my DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Below is my `DrawerNavigator`:

```
export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => null} },
    Permissions: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => null} },
    Explore: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => 'Explore'} },
    ContactScreen: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => 'Contact & Support'} },
    TOU: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => 'Terms of Use'} },
    Privacy: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => 'Privacy Policy'} },
    Disclaimer: { screen: AppStack },
    Settings: { screen: AppStack, navigationOptions: {drawerLabel:() => null} },
},{
    initialRouteName:'Privacy'
});
```

When `<Drawer />` is called from App.js, it routes to `Home` and not `Privacy` as my `initialRouteName` should be doing. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You've listed `AppStack` as the screen name for each route.  I imagine your AppStack is created with StackNavigator({ ... }) and the initialRouteName is `Home`.